# How do I compute the mean from ASCII file data in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

In bash I can grep some time measurements from a log file like this

```
grep "time:" myLogfile.txt | cut -d' ' -f 3 >> timeMeasurements.txt

#timeMeasurements.txt
2.5
3.5
2.0
...
```

Now I would like to compute the mean value from the values in `timeMeasurements.txt`. What is the quickest way to do that in bash?
I know that there is gnuplot and R but it seems like one has to write some lengthy script for either one on them.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13731/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-min-max-median-and-average-of-a-list-of-numbers-in

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another way, using `sed` and `bc`:

```
sed 's/^/n+=1;x+=/;$ascale=1;x/n' timemeasurements.txt | bc
```

The sed expression converts the input to something like this:

```
n+=1;x+=2.5
n+=1;x+=3.5
n+=1;x+=2.0
scale=1;x/n
```

This is piped to `bc` which evaluates it line-by-line.

Answer (score 13):

Obligatory [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) version

```
$ datamash mean 1 < file
2.6666666666667
```

---

**ASIDE**: it feels like this really *should* be possible *natively* in `bc` (i.e. without using the shell, or an external program, to loop over input values). The GNU `bc` implementation includes a `read()` function - however it appears to be frustratingly difficult to get it to detect end-of-input. The best I could come up with is:

```
#!/usr/bin/bc

scale = 6
while( (x = read()) ) {
  s += x
  c += 1
}
s/c
quit
```

which you can then pipe file input to **provided you terminate input with any non-numeric character** e.g.

```
$ { cat file; echo '@'; } | ./mean.bc
2.666666
```

Comment: Not only shortest answer but exposes those interested in stats to a handy utility +1

Comment: This looks intriguingly short. Is there an apt-get version of datamash?

Comment: @mcExchange `sudo apt install datamash` was sufficient on my Ubuntu 16.04 VM.

Comment: Unfortunately on Ubuntu 14.04 it's not in the repositories ...

Answer (score 12):

You could use `awk`. Bash itself is not very good at maths...

```
awk 'BEGIN { lines=0; total=0 } { lines++; total+=$1 } END { print total/lines }' timeMeasurements.txt
```

#### Notes

- `lines=0; total=0` set variables to 0
- `lines++` increase `lines` by one for each line
- `total+=$1` add the value in each line to the running total
- `print total/lines` when done, divide the total by the number of values

Comment: Although it's good practice, variables don't actually *need* to be initialized in `awk` - so you could "golf" this to `awk '{total+=$1} END{print total/NR}'`

Comment: @steeldriver thanks! Just starting to learn :)

Answer (score 8):

Adapting the R command from [this U&L post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13775/70524):

```
$ Rscript -e 'd<-scan("stdin", quiet=TRUE)' -e 'cat(mean(d), sep="\n")' < foo
2.666667
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `bc` the basic calculator, in a `while` loop with `read`:

```
count=0; sum=0; while read -r num; do ((count++)); sum=$(echo "$sum + $num" | bc); done < timeMeasurement.txt; echo "scale=2; $sum / $count" | bc -l
```

Or more readably:

```
count=0
sum=0
while read -r num
do
  ((count++))
  sum=$(echo "$sum + $num" | bc)
done < timeMeasurement.txt
echo "scale=2; $sum / $count" | bc -l
```

Explanation:

- First we set the count of values and the sum total as the variables
  count and sum, with values of 0.
- Read the file line by line, setting the value in the line as the variable num. We use the construction `while read -r num; do ... ; done < timeMeasurements.txt` to do this. This will mean that we'll do something for each line of the file.
- Within the while loop, increment the count variable by one for each line with bash arithmetic `((count++))`.
- Use bash command substitution `$(...)` with `echo` piped to `bc` to add the value of the num variable for this line of the file, to the sum of the num variable from all previous lines. `bc` is used as bash does not cope well with floating point arithmetic.

At this point the loop ends, the count variable contains the number of time measurement values, the sum variable contains the sum of the time measurements.

- Use `echo` with our variables to create the mean calculation which is passed to `bc`. The `scale=2` part tells `bc` how many significant figures to display.

Answer (score 4):

The datamash one seems a good option, but even acknowledging that my answer may be overkill, just in case you want to do a bit more than just a mean, octave is not so verbose:

```
$ octave
octave:1> load timeMeasurements.txt 
octave:2> mean(timeMeasurements)
ans =  2.6667
```

If you are doing means, remember that the same mean could come from very different behaviours, so the standard deviation is usually also relevant:

```
octave:3> std(timeMeasurements)
ans =  0.76376
```

or even a simple histogram is easy to do:

```
octave:4> hist(timeMeasurements)
```

Also, I think datamash is not in the apt-get repositories for trusty, only for newer versions.

#### Edit:

Oneliner, for more script-friendly usages:

```
octave -q --eval "m = load(\"timeMeasurements.txt\"); mean(m)"
```